# MDCBottomSheetController soft keyboard avoid pushing View up

Tags: ios, swift, bottom-sheet, ios-keyboard-extension, material-components-ios

I am using MDCBottomSheetController

following is my code to present bottom sheet controller

```
 let bottomSheet: MDCBottomSheetController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: viewController)
    // Present the bottom sheet

    bottomSheet.shouldFlashScrollIndicatorsOnAppearance = true;
    if openFor == SearchBottomSheetViewController.OPEN_FOR_DATE {
        bottomSheet.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height:  self.view.frame.size.height * 0.3)
    }else {
        bottomSheet.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 3 * self.view.frame.size.height / 4)
    }

    // bottomSheet.dismiss(animated: <#T##Bool#>, completion: <#T##(() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>)
    present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When ever soft key board is shown bottom sheet ui is pushed up I don't want UI to be pushed up when keyboard is shown

Refer to below gif for issue

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue, please peer review my edit, I have added the material-component-ios tag so that the guys there can find it and possibly provide an answer.

Comment: approved reported issue on github as well please add comment there as well here is link  https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios-codelabs/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that successfully, use the code below. (Just add the `removeKeyboardObserver()` function in your `viewDidLoad()`.)

```
func removeKeyboardObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(MDCKeyboardWatcher.shared()!)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing() {
    MDCKeyboardWatcher.load()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Suggested Solution**

Increase the constant of text field's top constraint.

**Reasoning**

Trial and error.